# Aligning pandas values ​to the left

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an error after aligning the values ​​of a pandas dataframe

I have an error after aligning the values ​​of a pandas dataframe:

```
print(df)

  icone        commoditie variação
0           Petróleo WTI    2,65%
1         Petróleo Brent    0,00%
2                  Prata    0,20%
3                   Ouro   -0,62%
4       Minério de Ferro   +0,68%
```

need to align everything to the left and then play for string

I can do it perfectly with:

```
df.reset_index(drop = True).style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

but then when I try to check the data or pass to a string it stops being a dataframe .... and I can't bring it back

```
df.head()
```

erro:

```
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Comment: have you assigned the result of that back to `df`? If so - then don't :)

Comment: Yes, I did......

Comment: Applying styler on df changes it's type (obviously :P). Styler appears to be last step of visualization processes, which usually happens at the end data analysis. Check this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/style-pandas-dataframe-like-a-master-6b02bf6468b0

Comment: I'm using the style wrongly then, this is not where I want it. I just want to remove these spaces from the string